# React Native setState add's last item of the array

Tags: react-native

So i got a `setState` named `items` `const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);`

**My Items Array Structure**

```
[{
  "id": "0.625240011345925",
  "item_name": "Item 23",
  "item_price": "23",
  "item_qty": "1"
}, {
  "id": "0.735657461482515",
  "item_name": "Item 4",
  "item_price": "30",
  "item_qty": "1"
}, {
  "id": "0.287635530963835",
  "item_name": "Item 2",
  "item_price": "56",
  "item_qty": "1"
}]
```

**Main Function**

```
    const AddItemToBill = (navigation) => {
    navigation.navigate('AddItemToBill', {
        onReturn: (itemArray) => {
            const array = itemArray;
            for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                const element = array[i];
                setItems([...items, element]);
                console.log('Items: ' + JSON.stringify(array))
            }
        }, navigation
    })
};
```

**Check issue in below Gif**

[image]

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Comment: @AseemGautam you can clearly see. **when i add 3 items the function just adds tha last item of the array**, i want all items to be added & i'm stuck

Comment: `setItems` is `useState` hook?

Comment: @AseemGautam Yes. `const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);`

Comment: `setItems([...items, ...newState]);`,
and I dont sure why you looping through just for pushing all elements one by one, why you don't spread `itemArray` and that it?

Comment: @HagaiHarari thanks for your suggetion, it worked fro me can u reply this as an ans so i can vote u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React `setState` is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately). Updated state is only available on the next render cycle. So adding multiple items in a for loop would only result in the last item being updated.

[Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) -
Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns.

Correct way is to build a new intermediate array & update state once -

```
const array = itemArray;
const newState = []; // array to hold the final state
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const element = array[i];
    // update the array for the final state
    // DO NOT UPDATE STATE HERE
    newState.push(element);
    console.log('Items: ' + JSON.stringify(array))
}
// update state ONCE outside forloop
setItems([...items, newState]);
```

Comment: This is what being added to `setItems` `[[{"id":"0.625240011345925","item_name":"Item 23","item_price":"23","item_qty":"1"}]]`

Comment: Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: please check the edited question

Comment: @newdevv2  I think this is the correct answer except for one thing: `setItems([...items, newState]);` this line is wrong and should be replaced with `setItems([...items, ...newState]);` with the spread operator in `newState` otherwise this will add a sub array into array. Am I right @Assem Gautam?

Answer (score 1):

As you are looping for getting all the elements, you can just spread directly `itemArray`

```
 onReturn: (itemArray) => {
                setItems(prev => ([...prev, ...itemArray]));
            }
```

Also used `prev` and not `items` state directly as a safety that it will always be called with the last value of the array in case a user make two quick interactions in a row